# validating signature using EC public key in openssl causing crash while freeing ECKey

Tags: c, openssl, ecdsa

I have EC Public key coordinates "x" and "y" which are 64 bytes string. I have a message which has to be validated with signature I have. I have written a function as shown below. Below function is crashing while freeing the key using line EC_KEY_free(ec_key). If I comment this line no crash is observed. Require your inputs/hints why this line is causing a problem. Thanks for your guidance.

For example public key "x" and "y" values are

```
x is 5CA6D40011278E3FF84FD94DD80E370CD90F2A304E9CEFB946082AB82FF0DBDE 
y is C05CA8BC76B1BF49C085672B76D19368394F2EDEF4A11D492BE34F14F3803AD1
```

After using BIGNUM with above values. I have BN print values as shown below

```
BIGNUM x coordinate:  0x5CA6D40011278E3FF84FD94DD80E370CD90F2A304E9CEFB946082AB82FF0DBDE
BIGNUM y coordinate:  0xC05CA8BC76B1BF49C085672B76D19368394F2EDEF4A11D492BE34F14F3803AD1

int verifySignature(const unsigned char* message, size_t message_len, const unsigned char* signature, size_t signature_len, const char* public_key_x, const char* public_key_y) {
    int result = 0;
    EC_KEY* ec_key = NULL;
    EC_POINT* ec_point = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY* public_key = NULL;
    EVP_MD_CTX* md_ctx = NULL;

    // parse public key
    BIGNUM* x = BN_new();
    BIGNUM* y = BN_new();

    if (!BN_hex2bn(&x, public_key_x)) {
        perror("Error parsing public key x coordinate");
        return -1;
    }

    printBN("BIGNUM x coordinate: ", x);

    if (!BN_hex2bn(&y, public_key_y)) {
        perror("Error parsing public key y coordinate");
        return -1;
    }

    printBN("BIGNUM y coordinate: ", y);

    /*
      An EC_KEY represents a public key and (optionaly) an associated private key.
      A new EC_KEY (with no associated curve) can be constructed by calling EC_KEY_new. 
      The reference count for the newly created EC_KEY is initially set to 1.
      A curve can be associated with the EC_KEY by calling EC_KEY_set_group.

      Alternatively a new EC_KEY can be constructed by calling EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name
      and supplying the nid of the associated curve. Run "openssl ecparam -list_curves" for curve names. 
      This function simply wraps calls to EC_KEY_new and EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name.
    */
    // Create the EC key with the curve SECP256R1.
    if ((ec_key = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating EC key\n");
        goto end;
    }

    // Create the EC point. EC_KEY_get0_group returns the EC_GROUP associated with the EC_KEY.
    if ((ec_point = EC_POINT_new(EC_KEY_get0_group(ec_key))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating EC point\n");
        goto end;
    }

    // Set the x and y coordinates of the point
    if (!EC_POINT_set_affine_coordinates_GFp(EC_KEY_get0_group(ec_key), ec_point, x, y, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting EC point coordinates\n");
        goto end;
    }

    // Set the public key for the EC key
    if (!EC_KEY_set_public_key(ec_key, ec_point)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting EC public key\n");
        goto end;
    }

    // Assign the EC key to the EVP_PKEY
    if ((public_key = EVP_PKEY_new()) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating EVP_PKEY\n");
        goto end;
    }

    if (!EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(public_key, ec_key)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error assigning EC key to EVP_PKEY\n");
        goto end;
    }

    // Create the message digest context
    if ((md_ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new()) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating message digest context\n");
        goto end;
    }

    // Initialize the message digest context with SHA-256 and the public key
    if (!EVP_DigestVerifyInit(md_ctx, NULL, EVP_sha256(), NULL, public_key)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing message digest context\n");
        goto end;
    }

    // Update the message digest context with the message
    if (!EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate(md_ctx, message, message_len)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error updating message digest context\n");
        goto end;
    }

    // Verify the signature
    result = EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(md_ctx, signature, signature_len);
    printf("Result: %d\n", result);

end:
    if (result != 1) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }

    if (md_ctx != NULL) EVP_MD_CTX_free(md_ctx);
    if (public_key != NULL) EVP_PKEY_free(public_key);
    if (ec_point != NULL) EC_POINT_free(ec_point);
```

> **if (ec_key != NULL) EC_KEY_free(ec_key); // FIXME: here it crashes**

```
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the [EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY.html) function:

> EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(), EVP_PKEY_assign_DSA(), EVP_PKEY_assign_DH(),
> EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(), EVP_PKEY_assign_POLY1305() and
> EVP_PKEY_assign_SIPHASH() set the referenced key to key however these
> use the supplied key internally and so key will be freed when the
> parent pkey is freed.

This means that by calling EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY you are transfering "ownership" of the EC_KEY to the EVP_PKEY and it will free it for you when you free the EVP_PKEY (EVP_PKEY_free call). So the call to EC_KEY_free is freeing it for a second time causing the crash.

So a fix would be:

```
if (!EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(public_key, ec_key)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error assigning EC key to EVP_PKEY\n");
    goto end;
}
ec_key = NULL; // public_key now owns ec_key so we give up control of it
```